# Inherit Document Set name to documents

Tags: document, document-set, inheritance

I have set up a Document Sets, and the documents inherits various things perfectly (`category`, `sub-category`, `company name` etc.).

However I can't figure out how to make the documents inherit the name of the Document Set (which in my case is an unique ID connected to SAP). Is this in any way possible?

Right now it is possible to substract this information from the path of the documents (as they are sub-level), but it would be perfect if this could be obtained otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I can think of is to create a new column in your document set content type and call it something like `DocSetName`.

Change your document set's settings to add this new column to the columns that will be synchronised with all files in the document set.

Create a simple workflow which starts when a new item (document set) is created, which copies the document set's name to this new column.